# Delta table optimization manual VS. auto

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have some delta format files need to optimize regularly.
According to this doc [write-conflicts-on-databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/optimizations/isolation-level.html#write-conflicts-on-databricks), `OPTIMIZE` explicitly can cause conflicts in some cases like `UPDATE`.

Meanwhile, with the latest Delta functionality, we can set the table properties:

`delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact` and `delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite`

which will enable the auto optimization.

My questions are --

1. Does the "auto optimize" will resolve the writing conflicts at the backend (especially for update)?
2. Is there any performance downgrade after enabling "auto optimize"?
3. In which case should I still use `OPTIMIZE` explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

As per [databricks documentaion](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/tune-file-size.html#auto-compact)
Control the output file size by below the Spark configuration `spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.maxFileSize`.

Auto compaction can be enabled at the table or session level using the following settings:
**Table property:** `delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact`
**SparkSession setting:** `spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled`

Optimized writes can be enabled at the table or session level using the following settings:
**Table setting:** `delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite`
**SparkSession setting:** `spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled`

As you said **OPTIMIZE** explicitly can cause conflicts in some cases like **UPDATE**.

I have reproduced to **UPDATE** records  and  see if **OPTIMIZE** can cause conflicts.

I have created a delta table and did an update on the table.
When I query the delta table spark engine fetch the latest version(.json) it gives the snapshot of the delta table.

***Note: In delta table if we DELETE(or) UPDATE the older version will not be deleted because of the Time Travel feature in databricks***

[image]

**Versioining Logs:**
[image]

When you perform **UPDATE** in the file system new file gets added because we updated 1 REC, so it is going to retain the old file.

**OPTIMIZE** command mainly used to compact the smaller files in delta lake. Too many smaller files will impact performance.
The better approach is optimal partitions or size.

[image]
[image]
**After Optimize:**
[image]

Optimize does file compacting all part files into 1 file and creating a .json as a reference to the latest snapshot of the delta table.

Know more about [When to run OPTIMIZE](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/tune-file-size.html#when-to-run-optimize)